# Azure Publish Database Location

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When creating a database via the Azure publish functionality in Visual Studio, I get the Region option for my site. If I choose East US, all is fine except my database ends up being created in South East Asia.

There's no option for specifying where to locate the database when publishing, so how to fix this problem?